# Post request de postman returns html status: 200

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, postman, spring-security

Tengo una aplicasion de spring boot que guarda a un usuario en una base de datos
la clase RegistrationController recive una request @Postmapping y la mapea a otra clase llamada RegistrationRequest

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "api/v1/registration")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {
    
     private   final RegistrationService registrationService;
     
    @PostMapping
    
    public String register (@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {     
    
        return registrationService.register(request);
    }

}
```

Despues  tengo otra clase RegistrationService  que la genera un nuevo usuario para la aplicacion y lo guarda en la base de datos esta clase ulitliza

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationService {
    
    private final  AppUserService appUserService;
    private  final EmailValidator emailValidator;
    

    public  String register(RegistrationRequest request) {
         boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.test(request.getEmail());
         
         
         if (!isValidEmail) {
             throw new  IllegalStateException("Email is not valid");
         }
         
        return appUserService.singUpUser(new AppUser(
                request.getFristName(),
                request.getLastName(),
                request.getEmail(), 
                request.getPassword(), 
                AppUserRole.USER)
                );
        
         
    }

}
```

La clase appUser es el modelo que va a guardar en la base de datos Usa un servicio para entra en spring sequrity asi

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AppUserService  implements UserDetailsService{
    
    private final static String USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG = "user with email %s not found";
    private final AppUserRepository appUserRepository;
    
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return appUserRepository.findByEmail(email).
                orElseThrow( ()-> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_MSG, email)));
    }

    
public String singUpUser (AppUser appUser) {
    
        boolean userExist = appUserRepository.findByEmail(appUser.getEmail()).isPresent();
        
        if(userExist) {
            
            throw new IllegalStateException("email already exist");
            
        }
        
        
        
         String  encodedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(appUser.getPassword());
         
         appUser.setPassword(encodedPassword);
         
         
         appUserRepository.save(appUser);
         
         //TO DO  send confirmation token
         
         return "it works";
         
    }
    
    
    }
```

Quiero que la repuesta de mi postman sea "it works" pero en ves me regresa un HTML  con status:200 ok

Answer (score 0):

Bien podes especificarle a spring que retorne un texto plano (`text/plain`) o "envolviendo" (*wrap*) tu `String` de respuesta en un objeto.

- **Retornando un objeto:** creas el objeto de retorno

```java
public class StringResponse {
    private String response;
    public StringResponse(String s) { 
       this.response = s;
    }
    // get y set ...
}
```

Y se agrega la anotación de que la respuesta va a ser un JSON

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/registration", consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
public StringResponse register (@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
```

- **Especificar retorno como texto plano:** En la notación de spring cambiar `@PostMapping` por

```java
@RequestMapping(value="/api/v1/registration", method=POST, produces="text/plain")
```

**ACLARACIONES:**

- Cambiar la notación `@PostMapping` por `RequestMapping` no es recomendado ya que la primera anotación viene a simplificar el uso de la segunda. De ir con esa solución deberías buscarle una vuelta a la especificación de `text/plain`.
- Si el procesamiento de la petición resulta en "exitoso" y no indicas otro tipo de *status code*, en el header de la respuesta HTTP se va a mandar un 200 que es un OK. Esto (mandar o no mandar un *satus code* y un *status message*) no es algo que puedas modificar ya que es parte del [protocolo](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview)
  [image: HTTP_response]
- Dices que en tu postman recibes un HTML, puedes cambiar la forma en la que lees la respuesta del servicio
  [image: postman_response_view]